# How to reset ifconfig counters?

Tags: 12.04, networking, reset, ifconfig

When i run `ifconfig eth0` see following lines:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:42:81:a7  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe42:81a7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:66 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:212 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8001 (8.0 KB)  TX bytes:34004 (34.0 KB)
```

How can i reset these counters especially **RX/TX packets**?

Comment: While you may not want to do this, it worth noting that you can also just restart your computer. :)

Comment: Yes you can reset counters by restarting your computer, but is it a good choice? Is it comfortable to close all programs and restart computer to just reset some counters? You suggest **Restart Engineering** dude, it is not a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those counters are kept by the kernel, so your answer depends on how your network card driver is built. Two possible choices:

1. Kernel module
2. Inside the kernel

If it is second, you can not reset counters without restarting the operating system. If it is first, you can do it by unloading the module from the kernel and then loading it back again. If your NIC card use *e1000* module, use following commands:

```
$ ifconfig eth0 down
$ modprobe -r e1000
$ modprobe e1000
$ ifconfig eth0 up
```

Use `ethtool` to find out your NIC module:

```
$ ethtool -i eth0
```

In front of **driver** you see your module name:

```
driver: e1000
version: 7.3.21-k8-NAPI
firmware-version: 
...
```

Use `apt-get` to install `ethtool` as follow:

```
$ apt-get install ethtool
```

Comment: `modprobe -r` unloads the driver from the kernel (which could leave you without a method of accessing the machine), so if you are doing this remotely I would advise just rebooting instead.

Comment: @Score_Under: A better solution for remote access is writing these command to a bash script file and then run it with `nohup`, i.e: `nohup bash restart_counters_script.sh`

Comment: Do you know how  can I do this with loopback interface? Also: [is possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164057/how-can-i-manually-reset-rx-tx-counters-in-ifconfig-output-without-impacting-d#comment663673_167353) to just unbind/bind the driver without removing the kernel module?

Comment: i had to sleep after modprobe... but after that, it works!