# How to monitor total data received/sent for current Wi-Fi session?

Tags: networking, wireless, monitoring

Like in Windows OS, I look for a way to see how much data has been used since I connected to a Wi-Fi network. I only came accross with `vnstat`, however, either it cannot provide what I want, or I could not manage to do it.

My desired operation:

I connected to a wi-fi at 1:00 pm let's say. Then at 2:00 pm, I wanted to see how much data I have used so far. What should I do?

Thanks.

p.s : Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options for that:

1) you can refer to the output of `ifconfig <name_of_your_interface>`:

```
$ /sbin/ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet [redacted]  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 [redacted]  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether [redacted]  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2911989  bytes 3104700566 (2.8 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1741814  bytes 307260264 (293.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

In the RX bytes line, you have the number of received bytes

```
        RX packets 2911989  bytes 3104700566 (2.8 GiB)
```

In the TX bytes line, you have the number of sent bytes

```
        TX packets 1741814  bytes 307260264 (293.0 MiB)
```

2) Refer to [How to get TX/RX bytes without ifconfig?](https://serverfault.com/questions/533513/how-to-get-tx-rx-bytes-without-ifconfig):

```
cat /proc/net/dev
```

3) You can use `netstat -i` (columns RX-OK and TX-OK)

4) `ip -s link`

5) If you want a live usage, you can use `iftop` (may need to be installed with `apt`, needs root privileges)

Comment: Thanks, all of them are nice, however, I think none of them is capable of providing exactly what I want. The closest is `sudo iftop -i wlp2s0`, however, it looks like I have to call it to start recording data usage by myself. I was looking for something constantly doing that in background and then I want to get the information when I want. Your 1st option for example, does this kind of a thing but the problem with it is that it records all the past(I assume) not the current session.

Comment: Indeed, I was not able to find a proper solution, but found how to reset the RX/TX counters https://askubuntu.com/a/348043/1085382 (really impractical IMHO) Otherwise, you can use a mix of `nmcli` which tells you the current wifi endpoint you are connected to, and `vnstat` which monitors the network usage